# How to split string and keep delimeters in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that is a fluent english paragraph:

> The jammed disregard treks below a fat combat. The fuse succeeds
> around the cable! Any repent pole approves the suited milk. The
> fence prevails above the trade scarf.

I want to split the string on spaces `' '` and all puncuation marks etc.. like: `.,?!;:` but keep them in the string array.

I want the string to look like this after it's split:

```
The
jammed 
disregard
...
!

Any
...
```

So far I've been trying something like:

```
string s = "The jammed disregard treks below a fat combat. The fuse succeeds 
around the cable! Any repent pole approves the suited milk. The 
fence prevails above the trade scarf."

string[] splitStrings = Regex.Split(s, @"(?<=[.,?!;:])");
```

but I am unsure of how to include the spaces in the Regex

Edit: to avoid confusion: I am trying to extract each individual word, space, and punctuation from an english paragraph and put it into a string array (hope that helps).

Comment: Can you show what you want the result to be?

Comment: I've included what I want the result to look like, basically a string array that delimits on puncuation, spaces, etc.. and then will look like: ```string[] splitStrings = {'The', 'jammed', 'disregard' ...}```

Comment: why can't you use `s.Split(' ','(', '?', '<', '=', '[', '.', ',', '?', '!', ';', ':', ']', ')');`

Comment: @Andy because op wants to keep the split character,  not exclude it.

Comment: @Andy because I want the delimiters to be included after the split

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ that Regex keeps the end punctuations attached to the word for example: ```'combat.'``` sshould be ```'combat'``` and ```'.'```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something like this (going by your output)

```
var s = "The jammed disregard treks below a fat combat. The fuse succeeds around the cable! Any repent pole approves the suited milk. The fence prevails above the trade scarf.";

var split = Regex
   .Replace(s, @"([ .,?!;:])", Environment.NewLine + "$1" + Environment.NewLine)
   .Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var item in split)
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output**

```
The

jammed

disregard

treks

below

a

fat

combat
.

The

fuse

succeeds

around

the

cable
!

Any

repent

pole

approves

the

suited

milk
.

The

fence

prevails

above

the

trade

scarf
.
```

Comment: This question is confusing.. your answer is getting downvoted, but that's what he said he wants.

Comment: @Andy indeed, i am just going by the output

Comment: This is pretty good, but is there a way to get the spaces after the punctuation too?

Comment: @RyM note this is different to your example output, just a reminder to put as much effort and accuracy into your question as you can

Comment: @TheGeneral I am trying to edit so people can understand, sorry

Answer (score -2):

This should be enough for you

```
char[] delimiters = new char[]{ ' ', ':', ...other chars];
string[] splitter = myString.Split(delimiters).ToArray();
```

Take note of the space which I put in the array

Comment: that's not what OP wants.